# How to compute the inverse of matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A=vu^T+I_d$. where $v=(v_1,v_2,..,v_n)^T$,$u=(u_1,u_2,..,u_n)^T$. I can compute the determinant of $A$ that is $\langle u,v \rangle +1$. So when $\langle u,v \rangle \neq -1$, we know $A$ has inverse, but how to compute it?

Comment: Gaussian elimination (yes I know I'm begin facetious)

Comment: How do you compute the determinant?

Comment: @user115350 Let $D_j$ denotes the determinant of $A=v_j u_j^T+I_d, v_j=(v_j,v_{j+1},..,v_n)^T, u_j=(u_j,u_{j+1},..,u_n)^T.$ You can compute the determinant easily after you finding the relationship bewteen $D_j$ and $D_{j+1}$

Comment: @user115350 $vu^T$ has rank $1$ which means that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ of multiplicity $n-1$, where $n$ is the size. This means that the missing eigenvalue is $\tr(A)-(n-1)=\tr(vu^T)+1=\langle u,v \rangle +1$, and hence $$\det(A)=  \langle u,v \rangle +1$$

Comment: @N.S. Your method is more efficient!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\lambda=\langle u,v \rangle$ and $B=vu^T$.

Then 
$$B^n= \lambda^{n-1} B$$

**Heuristically:** using the geometric series
$$(I+B)^{-1}= I+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n B^n = I+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\lambda^{n-1}B \\
 = I- B\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-\lambda)^{n}= I-\frac{1}{1+\lambda}B  $$

Note that the Heuristic calculation is actually a solution if $\| B \| <1$.

**Formal Proof** We show that $(I+B)^{-1}=I-\frac{1}{1+\lambda}B$. Indeed

$$(I+B)(I-\frac{1}{1+\lambda}B)=I+B-\frac{1}{1+\lambda}B-\frac{1}{1+\lambda}B^2 \\
=I+B-\frac{1}{1+\lambda}B-\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}B=I \\
$$

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-\lambda)^{n}$ cannot converge unless $|\lambda|<=1$. So when $|\lambda|>1$ how to compute this... I think there must be some ways to deal with it because this is a problem in a preliminary exam of our school

Comment: @Gatsby The Heuristic approach just shows HOW I found that the inverse is $I- \frac{1}{1+\lambda}B$, you can simply ignore that part. The proof is basically the following: Since $(I+B)(I-\frac{1}{1+\lambda}B)=I$ it follows that $(I+B)^{-1}=I-\frac{1}{1+\lambda}B$.... Remember, if you know what the inverse is, it is trivial to prove that that is the inverse... The hard part is FINDING the inverse, but once you know it, the proof is trivial: you just multiply them.

Comment: @Gatsby I only added that part because you might wonder how I guessed that the inverse is exactly $I-\frac{1}{1+\lambda}B$....